# Python shuffle the middle letters in all the words of a sentence

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, shuffle

The purpose of the program is to shuffle only the middle letters of each word in a sentence, leaving it still readable like this:

> Aoccdrnig to a rscheearch at Cmabrigde Uinervtisy, it deosn't mttaer in waht oredr the ltteers in a wrod are, the olny iprmoetnt tihng is taht the frist and lsat ltteer be at the rghit pclae.

```
def garble(sentence):

    return ' '.join([word[0] + ''.join(random.sample([char for char in word[1:-1]],len(word[1:-1]))) + word[-1] if len(word) > 1 else word for word in  sentence.split()])
```

I definitely think I have gone overboard putting it all in one line but I'm not sure where to separate it

Comment: And if you look at [this research](https://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/matt.davis/cmabridge/) (actually by a Cambridge University researcher) you will find that it's mostly false.

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9355/32352 for an extreme example of compressing everything in one line...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I totally agree with [@alecxe](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/24208)'s comment on Python, but I thing regex is a little overkill for this problem. So, here's a non-regex solution:

```py
import random

def shuffle_string(string):
    chars = list(string)
    random.shuffle(chars)
    return ''.join(chars)

def garble_word(word):
    # No operation needed on sufficiently small words
    # (Also, main algorithm requires word length >= 2)
    if len(word) <= 3:
        return word

    # Split word into first & last letter, and middle letters
    first, mid, last = word[0], word[1:-1], word[-1]

    return first + shuffle_string(mids) + last

def garble(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(' ')
    return ' '.join(map(garble_word, words))
```

Edit: It should be noted that while my solution is simpler than @alecxe's, it is not as robust. If you care about dealing with strange whitespace properly, or about handling punctuation (see @RolandIllig's comment), use @alecxe's solution.

Comment: The `*mids` requires Python 3.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson True, but the question is tagged "python-3.x" Updated regardless.

Comment: Your code considers `ear,` a valid garbling for the "word" `are,`.

Comment: `*mids` already provide a list of characters, no need to `chars = list(string)` in `shuffle_string` (unless Python 2…)

Comment: I like this one slightly better because it uses a more similar technique to mine

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Ah, good catch! I've switched to `mids = string[1:-1]` (although it's not quite as pretty) since using a string reflects concept better than a char list.

Comment: @RolandIllig Correct, I was going for a simpler but less robust solution. My code also handles having two spaces in a row improperly (it gives the correct result, but by passing around a `''` as a word, when really there is no word there). I'll edit just to note these limitations.

Answer (score 20):

The fact that Python allows fitting things on a single line and pack in comprehensions, does not mean you need to try to squash the code to be shorter hurting readability. I would probably at least expand the code into multiple lines with descriptive variable names.

Here is, though, an alternative solution based on *regular expression replacement function*:

```
from random import shuffle
import re


RE_GARBLE = re.compile(r"\b(\w)(\w+)(\w)\b")


def garble_word(match):
    first, middle, last = match.groups()

    middle = list(middle)
    shuffle(middle)

    return first + ''.join(middle) + last


def garble(sentence):
    return RE_GARBLE.sub(garble_word, sentence)
```

Comment: I've not used regex before. Could you explain what is being passed to garble_word()?

Comment: @Joe sure, the `match` is a ["Match" object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects), that allows us to access the captured groups via `.groups()`. A good place to start with regular expressions is the [How To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) from the standard library documentation.

Comment: The regex is for word extraction (not for garbling), and should be named appropriately.

Comment: I would also expect `garble_word` function to take a word string as an input, not some regex match object.

Comment: @n0rd well, here `garble_word()` is a replacement function for the `re.sub()` which expects an argument to be a "match" object..just following the contract/rules..thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to split up the line. Something like the following is way more readable.

```
def garble(sentence):
    words = []
    for word in  sentence.split():
        if len(word) > 1:
            words.append(word[0]
                       + ''.join(random.sample(
                         [char for char in word[1:-1]], len(word) - 2))
                       + word[-1])
        else:
            words.append(word)
    return ' '.join(words)
```

Comment: you can probably make this a little faster by using `if len(word) > 3`, since one, two, and three letter words are all unchanged.

Comment: yeah, I just kept the 1 to keep consistency with the original